# Proxy Server refuses connection after short period of time

Tags: internet, proxy, lan

I have a freshly installed ubuntu version 14.04 running on my Lenovo G780 (only later I learned that this Laptop may not be the ideal choice for a Linux system). Please note that I have never really used a Linux system before; I might need some thorough explanation and I apologize in advance.
My situation: I am online using a LAN cable. I am staying in a universitary guesthouse that provides Internet access after successful login on an authentification page that opens first thing after connecting the cable. To do this, I had to connect via a proxy server. 
Now the problem: After a couple of minutes in which I can access the Internet without problems, the connection breaks down and the "proxy server refuses connections", as Firefox told me. When I unplug the cable and put it back in, the cycle starts again: For a variable, but not very long time, I have Internet before the connection breaks down again. I have the feeling that it may depend in part on the amount of data that is processed; Trying to run a video stream or a skype call lets the connection crash almost immediately, while if I leave it alone, the connection sometimes stays open for almost an hour. 
Does anybody have an idea? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Does anyone else near you have the same problem?

Comment: I fear that there is no one else. The guesthouse only has 4 rooms or something like that, only one of which is occupied - by me. But before I installed ubuntu, I used Windows 8 on the same laptop in the same room with same cable and proxy settings, which worked fine.